# Kendo ui Scheduler- JSON Data not displaying

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm trying to use the Kendo Scheduler to show 3 different calendars.  The scheduler itself is displaying properly, but the data is not being populated/displayed.  I'm very new to JavaScript and I cannot seemed to figure out where the issue is.  There are no errors on the page and it looks like it can see the JSON file, but is just not displaying the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here's the code:

```
<div id="example">
<div id="team-schedule">
    <div id="people">
        <input checked type="checkbox" id="fcpi" value="2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rpr" value="3">
        <input checked type="checkbox" id="aaspg" value="1">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
    date: new Date("2016/1/13"),
    startTime: new Date("2016/1/13 07:00AM"),
    height: 600,
    views: [
        "day",
        "workWeek",
        "week",
        { type:"month", selected: true},
        "agenda"
    ],
    timezone: "Etc/GMT",
    dataSource: {
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "./calendars/Fiscal.json",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "taskId",
                fields: {
                    taskId: { from: "TaskID", type: "number" },
                    title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                    start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                    end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                    startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                    endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                    description: { from: "Description" },
                    recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                    recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                    recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                    ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: "1", type: "number" },
                    isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                }
            }
        },
        filter: {
            filters: [
                { field: "ownerId", operator: "eq", value: '1' }
            ]
        }
    },
    resources: [
        {
            field: "ownerId",
            title: "Owner",
            dataSource: [
                { text: "AA & SPG Pay Run", value: '1', color: "#f8a398" },
                { text: "Foster Care Phone In", value: '2', color: "#51a0ed" },
                { text: "Residential Pay Run", value: '3', color: "#56ca85" }
            ]
        }
    ]
    });

$("#people :checkbox").change(function(e) {
    var checked = $.map($("#people :checked"), function(checkbox) {
        return parseInt($(checkbox).val());
    });

    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");

    scheduler.dataSource.filter({
        operator: function(task) {
            return $.inArray(task.ownerId, checked) >= 0;
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

And then some of the JSON data too:

```
[{"TaskID":1,"OwnerID":1,"Title":"AA & SPG Paid","Description":"AA: 1/1/2016 - 1/31/2016    SPG: 12/1/2015 - 12/31/2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1453334400)\/","End":"\/Date(1453420800)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":2,"OwnerID":1,"Title":"AA & SPG Supplemental","Description":"AA: 1/1/2016 - 1/31/2016    SPG: 12/1/2015 - 12/31/2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1453334400)\/","End":"\/Date(1453420800)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":3,"OwnerID":1,"Title":"Approve Payments","Description":"AA: 1/1/2016 - 1/31/2016    SPG: 12/1/2015 - 12/31/2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1452038400)\/","End":"\/Date(1452124800)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":4,"OwnerID":1,"Title":"Approve Payments","Description":"AA: 1/1/2016 - 1/31/2016    SPG: 12/1/2015 - 12/31/2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1452124800)\/","End":"\/Date(1452211200)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":5,"OwnerID":1,"Title":"Sent to Edison AA & SPG Supplemental","Description":"AA: 1/1/2016 - 1/31/2016    SPG: 12/1/2015 - 12/31/2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1452211200)\/","End":"\/Date(1452297600)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":6,"OwnerID":2,"Title":"Approve Payments","Description":"Pay Period: 1/1/16 - 1/15/16","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1453161600)\/","End":"\/Date(1453248000)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":7,"OwnerID":2,"Title":"Approve Payments","Description":"Pay Period: 1/1/16 - 1/15/16","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1453248000)\/","End":"\/Date(1453334400)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":8,"OwnerID":2,"Title":"Foster Phone In","Description":"Pay Period: 1/1/16 - 1/15/16","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1453334400)\/","End":"\/Date(1453420800)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":9,"OwnerID":3,"Title":"Residential Refresh","Description":"Refresh: 9/1/15 - 11/30/15|Final Refresh for Sept.","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1453248000)\/","End":"\/Date(1453334400)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":10,"OwnerID":3,"Title":"Residential Pay Run ","Description":"Pay Period: 12/1/15 - 12/31/15|December 2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1452038400)\/","End":"\/Date(1452124800)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":11,"OwnerID":3,"Title":"Residential Pay Run ","Description":"Pay Period: 12/1/15 - 12/31/15|December 2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1452124800)\/","End":"\/Date(1452211200)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"},
{"TaskID":12,"OwnerID":3,"Title":"Residential Refresh","Description":"Refresh: 9/1/15 - 11/30/15|Sept. thru Dec. 2015","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1452211200)\/","End":"\/Date(1452297600)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":"false"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Data do not seem to be correct , I made an example.

I think the problem is with the start and end dates, they are not consistent.

```
var YourData =[{"TaskID":1,"OwnerID":2,"Title":"Bowling tournament","Description":"","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1370811600000)\/","End":"\/Date(1453420800)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":false}]; 

  var NewData =[{"TaskID":1,"OwnerID":2,"Title":"Bowling tournament","Description":"","StartTimezone":null,"Start":"\/Date(1453334400)\/","End":"\/Date(1370822400000)\/","EndTimezone":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"IsAllDay":false}];
```

YourData dont work, but the NewData is working, I just test with first item.

Here the example.

http://dojo.telerik.com/uTOQe

Hope this help

Comment: If my start and end dates are the issues, what is the best way to convert the human readable date into a unix timestamp?  I don't understand the start and end dates provided.  Is the start date in 2016, and your end date in 1970?  It looks like the Kendo demo uses milliseconds instead of seconds.  I'm trying to do the conversion in excel and then convert that data into json data.  I cannot seem to find a consistent way to convert and then check my data.

Comment: had you try somethig like : `var Date="26-02-2012";
Date=Date.split("-");
var newDate=Date[1]+"/"+Date[0]+"/"+Date[2];
alert(new Date(newDate).getTime());`